# Update a html select when a checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onchange

I have a strange behaviour with my js code.
I do a JsFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/wf8G6/2/

I want to update the "option selected" of a select when I check a particular checkbox...

Actually I have to click 3 times to trigger the event...

I check the checkbox => nothing happens
I uncheck the checkox => nothing happens
I check the checkbox => it works ...

Here is my HTML

```
<fieldset class="attribute_fieldset" rel="">
    <input class="left cb_group_5" type="checkbox" value="group_5" /> 

    <select name="group_5" id="group_5" class="attribute_select hidden">
        <option value="23" selected="selected" title="non">non</option>
        <option value="24" title="oui">oui</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Here is my JS

```
//if we check a checkbox, we trigger a click on the select below
$('.attribute_fieldset input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    var target = '#' + $(this).val();
    $(target + ' option').removeAttr('selected');
    if (this.checked) {
        $(target + ' option[title="oui"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
    } else {
        $(target + ' option[title="non"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
    $(target).trigger('change');
});
```

What I do wrong ? Please, help me community =)

Comment: I dont see any issue in the fiddle.

Comment: @karthikr , you had to click 3 times the ckeckbox for change the select... instead once

Comment: @f00bar English please.

Comment: No, it worked right away. First click, and the select dropdown value changed. I am on chrome

Comment: change `.attr()` to `.prop()`

Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: Its working just fine with one click!

Comment: FYI the title attribute is not valid on option elements. You might want to use the data attribute instead.

Comment: @putvande This was to get details, I would have translated it anyway `;)`

Comment: It seems the problem was only on firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you right you want your drop down to change depending on if you have clicked the checkbox.

In your code you have the line

`$(target + ' option').removeAttr('selected');`

Im not sure why you are removing the attribute selected from all your options, if you remove it your code works fine

```
$('.attribute_fieldset input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){

    var target = '#'+$(this).val();


    if(this.checked)
    {
        $(target+' option[title="oui"]').attr('selected','selected');
    }
    else
    {
        $(target+' option[title="non"]').attr('selected','selected');
    }


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wf8G6/3/

Also on a side note its better to not keep referencing you elements in the way you are, a more efficient way is like this

```
$('.attribute_fieldset input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){

    var target = $('#'+$(this).val());


    if(this.checked)
    {
        $('option[title="oui"]',target).attr('selected','selected');

    }
    else
    {
        $('option[title="non"]',target).attr('selected','selected');
    }


});
```

Comment: Indeed... it works. Thank you for the second alternative, it's cleaner.